# Internal Service Error when using not null in Geolocation SOQL

Tags: soql, geolocation

I have the following SOQL query which uses a geolocation field called `Location__c` to get the nearest 100 accounts to a location. I want to exclude any records that have a null value for Location__c but although the query compiles, it seems to cause an Internal Server Error.

```
Select Name, Postcode__c, Location__Latitude__s, Location__Longitude__s 
From Account 
Where Location__c != null 
Order By Distance(Location__c, GEOLOCATION(37.7945391,-122.3947166), 'mi') 
Limit 100
```

I have tried to catch the error in my controller, but it must be one that can't be caught...?

I can get around this in the short term by NULLS LAST in my Order By clause, but I wondered if anyone knew what the issue was. Is there anything wrong with my SOQL statement?

Thanks